# How do I convert a string to currency?

Tags: asp.net, sql

I'm developing an asp.net application that utilizes a sql database. I have a form which captures data from a user. If I have a text box that grabs a number, how do I convert that number to money before it goes to the database?

Comment: convert that number to money???

Comment: Probably first figure out what types of input you'll consider valid.

Comment: Hehe, I just saw the title as I was wandering through the front page; I was like: "dang, I want to know how to convert text to money, too! I have a lot more text than I do money." :D

Comment: @neminem I thought the same thing. I was about to recommend writting an epic, on the like of *Lord of the Rings* or *The Dark Tower*. Failing that, canned tween romances written *Twilight*-style will also give you a lot of money too.

Answer (score 2):

We normally store currency value in SQL server as [Money](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882.aspx).

You want to use [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557.aspx) so that your application won't crash if user enters invalid value.

```
decimal value;
if (decimal.TryParse(MyTextBox.Text, out value))
{
    // do something with value.
}
else
{
    // User enters invalid value. Display error message.           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to double, like this:

```
Convert.ToDouble("1.50"));
```